# Subgrid data retrival in crm

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-online

I have a sub-grid dynamics 365 crm named competitors I have to get data from that sub-grid and print it into alert. I have searched in the net but every solution I get from there when I used is throwing error as deprecated method. How can I get the sub-grid data in dynamics 365 application using JavaScript. Can anyone provide sample code for that.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is below code I tried in one of my Instance. Considering you want alert on Opportunity entity and that too onload of a form.

Use Debugger and you will get the data.

```
function onLoad(executionContext){
debugger;
   var formContext = executionContext.getFormContext();   
var formType= formContext.ui.getFormType();
if(formType && formType!==1 && formContext.data.entity.getId()){
    retreiveOppCompRecords(formContext.data.entity.getId().replace(/[{}]/g, "")).then(
            function success(result) {              
             if(result.entities.length > 0){
                 for(i=0;i<result.entities.length;i++){

                 }               
             }               

            },
            function (error) {
                var alertStrings = {
                    confirmButtonLabel: "OK",
                    text: 'Failed at Function: enableDisableExpiryDate with error: ' + error.message
                };
                var alertOptions = {
                    height: 250,
                    width: 450
                };
                Xrm.Navigation.openAlertDialog(alertStrings, alertOptions);
            }
        );
}
}


function retreiveOppCompRecords(recordId){
    var fetchxml = ['<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="false">',
  '<entity name="opportunity" >',
    '<attribute name="name" />',
    '<filter type="and" >',
      '<condition attribute="opportunityid" operator="eq" value="' + recordId + '" />',
    '</filter>',
    '<link-entity name="opportunitycompetitors" from="opportunityid" to="opportunityid" alias="OppCompetitor" intersect="true" >',
      '<link-entity name="competitor" from="competitorid" to="competitorid" link-type="inner" alias="Competitor" >',
        '<attribute name="websiteurl" alias="CompetitorWebsite" />',
        '<attribute name="name" alias="CompetitoName" />',
      '</link-entity>',
    '</link-entity>',
  '</entity>',
'</fetch>'].join("");

    fetchxml = "?fetchXml=" + encodeURIComponent(fetchxml); 
    return Xrm.WebApi.retrieveMultipleRecords("opportunity", fetchxml);
}
```

Comment: Thank you but I need to get data from subgrid in a page in other words I want to get to data from a subgrid in a form not form data

Comment: With above code you will get all the data from your competitors subgrid which is placed on opportunity entity. You could add as many fields in your fetchxml and get data.

Comment: @vamsisaggurthi did it helped? could you please mark it as solved if it does. It will help others as well.

Comment: I found another method you can check the answer below and thank you so much for your help because your code helped me in another problem solving

Answer (score 0):

As AnkUser has eluded to you need to retrieve the associated records from your subgrid adding in the `<attribute name=''>` tags as needed for the columns you need.

Remember a sub-grid is simply a view of data, usually, associated with the given record.

What specifically are you trying to retrieve from the subgrid?

Comment: Thank you But i didn't asked for html subgrid i asked for crm subgrid. I found answer already i have added an onload event to subgrid through javascript and retrieved data using Xrm.Page.getControl(“Contacts”).getGrid()

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer already - I have added an onload event to subgrid via JavaScript and retrieved data using `Xrm.Page.getControl(“entityname”).getGrid()`.

Comment: Thank you for editing the data. I was in hurry at that time due to office call. I didn't observed the typing mistakes. Thanks again for the help